# Magento 2.2.6 /var/lib/mysql/ folder is taking 43 gb of disk space

Tags: mysql, database, magento, magento2, innodb

Due to some reason my magento 2 website  **(Magento ver. 2.2.6)** taking too much space from the server . Yesterday there is 1.2 gb available now only 240mb available . Please help on this .

Please see the attached picture now

[image]

> UPDATE : **I have found that most of the disk space is taken by
>   /var/lib/mysql/webna** this folder **(42 gb)**.  Here webna is my database name .In that folder i can see **lots of IBD , FRM, MYI** files. There is on file inside the webna folder called **mageplaza_smtp_log.ibd and it's file size is 43 gb**.

Please see the below image 
[image]

**Can i delete these large files ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete these files, your Magento site will certainly stop working.

I would guess that the largest file `mageplaza_smtp_log` is storing the history of emails sent from your server. The more emails your site sends over time, and the larger the content of each email, the more will be stored in that tablespace.

This may be related to this feature: https://www.mageplaza.com/faqs/is-there-a-way-to-log-and-view-the-emails-sent-to-recipients.html

> **Is there a way to log and view the emails sent to recipients?**
>
> This can
>   be accessed by the following `Mageplaza > SMTP > Email Logs`. From here
>   you can look back all the sent email from the server to customers.
>   This log email can be cleaning periodically.

I recommend you figure out how to do what the last line says, clean out the log periodically if you don't need it. I am not a Magento user, but I suppose there's some control to do that on the screen they reference.

It would be best to use the Mageplaza screens to do this action, because if there is other internal bookkeeping necessary for Mageplaza to update multiple tables, only their code would know how to do that properly.

If you need more specific Magento help, there's a sister site to Stack Overflow specifically for Magento questions: https://magento.stackexchange.com

But I am sure that just deleting the files yourself will be very effective at breaking your site. Or at least the capability to send emails and view logs of past emails.